# What is the meaning of the PHP code "<?=$List?>"?

Tags: php

I knew there are two ways to represent PHP code start/end.

```
<?php ?>
```

and

```
<? ?>
```

---

In this code snippet:

```
<?php
for($x=5;$x<25;$x=$x+5):
$List .= '<option value="'.$x.'">Greater than '.$x.'% increase</option>';
endfor;
?>

<html>
...
<select name="growth" id="growth">
<option value="">Choose one</option>

<?=$List ?>
</select>

...
</html>
```

What is the meaning of the `<?=$List ?>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<?` is the shorthand version of the opening tag, `<?php`. The `=` means to echo the specified string/variable, so the whole thing is shorthand for:

```
<?php
echo $List
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php echo $List ?>
```

The shorttag syntax is deprecated though.